# Is it safe to use 7-Zip from a data corruption standpoint to archive 500GB of videos?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, encryption, 7-zip, archiving

Would it be okay to use 7-Zip to archive my almost 500GB videos in compression level store format only to my portable external hard drive. I just want to put it in one file with password for my future backup purposes.

Is it possible some of my files get corrupted if I leave it too long in my portable hard drive since I am not gonna use my drive unless needed.

If yes, how and what does cause this? I am afraid to loose some of my files because of archiving it.

Hope I get an answer soon. Thank you!

Comment: You should always have more than one backup for your important files as disks can potentially fail without warning. Backup files can also be deleted or overwritten by mistake. It is also import to periodically test that you can restore from the backups.

Comment: Additionally, all you will gain from encrypted 7z on video files is the encryption. You won't save any space. Video, photographs & audio all use compression already & are particularly resistant to the methods used by such as the zip structure. Having encryped data all in one 'basket' means if you lose one bit, you lose it all.

Comment: You mean it is not recommended or reliable to do this method?

Comment: I don't mind having it uncompressed. I just want it secured with password and save it on my USB and Portable hard drive for backup purposes.

Comment: If a video file can become corrupt then a .zip file can become corrupt.  Once a .zip file is corrupt you won't be able to extract the compressed file.

Comment: In essence, no file system is entirely free from potential corruption. What you need are several versions of the same backup, stored in different locations. Any one can fail at any time… or the house could burn down...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have titled your question "Does using 7zip increase the risk of data loss?" instead of "Is it safe to use 7zip from corruption?". The question "Is it OK" falls into the same category.

Refering to the proposed title the answer is "yes". You are increasing the risk of loss because your 7zip archive is in itself a file system. When you put an additional file system on a existing file system the risk increases.

If you imagine random failure of sectors at your current stage, most of them will only affect one file, in rare cases your partition will seem to be lost or the file system becomes unreadable.
Once you put your files in any kind of archive you generate additional locations where a random sector failure could have fatal consequences.

As you just seem to intend using encryption a different solution does not come with this disadvantage. When using Truecrypt or Veracrypt in device mode and having generated a backup of the header (very small!) you do not generate additional risk.

If it happens that a random sector failure hits your header area which is required to decipher your videos you don't have to worry because your header backup enables you to decipher nevertheless.

But if you use both products in file mode you are generating an additional file system on top of the file system of your drive, thus increasing risk.

Your contribution contains a second question as to file corruption. If the hard drive electronics contains a certain type of capacitor that will dry over time you will loose access to your data, too. For long time storage purposes just having backups is not enough. You will have to copy your content to new drives - but I can't tell how often - every five years maybe ten years? I would like to know myself.

Comment: I might as well copy my files directly instead of archiving it. I am not gonna risk losing a single one. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

### If these materials mean anything to you, store them archivally on on two or more hard drives without any compression.

The [accepted answer here by r2d3](https://superuser.com/a/1611623/167207) is solid and provides good advice but part of your question asks:

> “Is it possible some of my files get corrupted if I leave it too long in my portable hard drive since I am not gonna use my drive unless needed.”
>
> “If yes, how and what does cause this?”

Easy: [Bit rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_degradation) (aka: data degradation).

The reality is every bit of digital media out there is prone to bit rot simply from existing. The best way to prevent bit rot is to simply realize it exists and know two things:

- **Compression Won’t Make Files Less Susceptible to Bit Rot**: All compression does is compress the file. And if data in the compressed archive gets corrupted, you might actually *decrease* your risk of data recovery by applying compression to the file itself. Why? Easy: Some compression formats simply fail to decompress *any* file that has a damaged bit of data. Some are designed for better redundancy (see below) but they are few and far between and who knows if they will be supported in the future.
- **Redundancy is Your Safest Bet**: I have no idea how many files you have or how much physical space they take up on a drive, but if you care about that data you should have multiple drives to store that data. I don’t mean spreading the data across two drives, but two drives that have 100% the exact same data. The reason being is that bit rot is inconsistent. And let’s say — 10 years from now — both drives show bad sectors… But in different places… Then odds are good one drive will have a clean copy of some files and the other drive will have clean copies of others.

That said, you now might be thinking about USB flash drives and SSDs for long term backup and the jury is still out on those. Technically speaking flash-based storage media *should* last longer over time and be less prone to bit rot, but it all depends on long term NAND flash quality. And since flash-based storage is relatively new-ish, I wouldn’t bet my data on flash-based media for long term storage. Hard drives still have a solid history of being useful after years of non-use.

#### Use parity archives.

And before I mentioned that compression won’t help in the case of bit-rot, but one modern compression format *does* have self-healing properties: RAR

RAR compression tools can create [parity archives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive). And as the Wikipedia entry for [parity archives (Parchive)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive) states:

> “Parchive was originally written to solve the problem of reliable file sharing on Usenet, but it can be used for protecting any kind of data from data corruption, disc rot, bit rot, and accidental or malicious damage. Despite the name, Parchive uses more advanced techniques that do not use simplistic parity methods of error detection and correction.”

These magical parchives can reconstitute a damaged files and knowing that you can compress your videos and create parity archives for these compressed files that could be used to reconstitute the data files if they experience bit rot.

In a case like this I would recommend you compress individual videos files with parity archives for each archive and not one huge compressed archive. In that way, each video has its own parity archives. Or you can just create standalone parity archives for the video files and store them along with the original videos on a hard drive; same benefits but without compression.